# How do I make a block title output as a link?

Tags: views, theming, panels

I have a couple of Views block displays that are being shown inside of Panels content panes.  I am trying to get the block titles to be links to overview (static) pages.  The devel_themer module suggested that I make a template file named `panels-pane--block--views-case-studies-block-block.tpl.php` ("Case Studies Block" is the block name.)

When I try to load the page now, I get errors about undefined variables (block_html_id, block).

I think this probably has something to do with Panels and Views templates clashing, maybe?  I'm still getting my feet wet with theming/overrides.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!  And the answer doesn't involve other modules or theming at all!

If you go into the pane settings for the block, in the Panels settings (node template) there is a checkbox labeled, "Link title to view".  By itself, this didn't actually make a link at all.  However, if you go back into the same settings dialog, there is another field, down at the bottom, labeled, "Override URL". If you specify the path there, then it will correctly output the block title as a link!

Answer (score 5):

You can simply edit your View, and set the title of your view to this:

```
<a href="/mylink">My Link</a>
```

[image]

Click on Apply and then Save your view.

Answer (score 0):

Would the [Block Title Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_titlelink) module not provide your answer? Details from its project page:

> Have you ever needed to make a block title a link? This module makes it easy. Block Title Link creates a link field on the Block Admin page. It works by overriding the $block->subject variable and changes it to a link.

Might need to undo some of your custom theme code, but seems to do the job you're looking for.

Comment: It might, but I'd like to learn how to do it via template override, so that I can control other aspects, such as applying a class.